# Anime about a boy who jumps dimensions with his dog and a girl and meets a Omnyo mystic

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this years ago.

He lives in a town that’s being sold and destroyed, jumps dimensions with his friends and dog and meets a Omnyo mystic in one of the dimensions.

Comment: What is "Freon’s" ?

Comment: [Magical Shopping Arcade Abenobashi](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0398412/?ref_=tt_ov_inf), specifically this episode https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0935127/?

Comment: @DoscoJones - "friends", I expect

Comment: I expect too, but it's too big an assumption to just edit.

Comment: That is it thank you very much. and it was friends it has this has been bugging me for awhile

Answer (score 4):

This is [*Magical Shopping Arcade Abenobashi*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0398412/?ref_=tt_ov_inf).

> Two kids whose families own businesses in a shopping arcade that's scheduled to shut down are thrown into a series of dimensions, each one a parody of some form of anime or video game, and try to find their way home.

In one episode, [Return to Life! The Legendary Onmyou Mystic](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0935127/), the kids meet a mystic.

> Arumi and Sasshi have finally made there way home. But Arumi's grandfather will still be dead. Sasshi refuses to let that happen, so he jumps again into another world. But in the end he cannot dream away reality.